# set unique key checks 0

Tags: mysql

In a table i have unique value check for the combination of box_number,price,start_val,end_val

so there can not be a two box number with same number which have same price , start_val and end_val..

**table data right now**

```
| box_type_id | box_number | price |start_val | end_val
|  1          |   7        | 5.00  |100       |1
|  2          |   5        | 10.00 |50        |40
|  3          |   5        | 5.00  |100       |1
```

**what i want to do**
i want to change box number 7 with 5 for box_type_id 1 and change box number 5 with 7 for box type id 3 ; my query is below... giving me error

**MySQL Database Error: Duplicate entry '7-5.00-100-1' for key 'unique_index'**

but here i am setting unique key check to 0. before executing query.

**My query**

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
 Update `box_types` `bt` SET `bt`.`box_number` = "7" where `bt`.`box_type_id` = "3" ;
 Update `box_types` `bt` SET `bt`.`box_number` = "5" where `bt`.`box_type_id` = "1" ;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=1;
```

how do i solve this problem.. is there any other prblem ? please guide me..

**MY WHOLE TABLE**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `box_types` (
 `box_type_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `box_number` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'Box Number',
 `price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
 `start_val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `end_val` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
 `updated_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
 `created_by` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key from users     table user_id',
 `updated_by` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'foreign key from users table user_id'
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

ALTER TABLE `box_types`
ADD PRIMARY KEY (`box_type_id`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `unique_index`     (`box_number`,`price`,`start_val`,`end_val`), ADD KEY `created_by` (`created_by`), ADD KEY `updated_by` (`updated_by`), ADD KEY `status` (`status`);


ALTER TABLE `box_types`
MODIFY `box_type_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=4;


ALTER TABLE `box_types`
ADD CONSTRAINT `box_types_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`updated_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
ADD CONSTRAINT `box_types_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`created_by`) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION;



INSERT INTO `box_types` (`box_type_id`, `box_number`, `price`, `start_val`, `end_val`, `created_date`, `updated_date`, `status`, `created_by`, `updated_by`) VALUES
(1, 7, 5.00, 100, 1, '2015-02-16 08:29:39', NULL, 1, 1, NULL),
(2, 5, 10.00, 50, 40, '2015-02-16 08:30:05', NULL, 1, 1, NULL),
(3, 5, 5.00, 100, 1, '2015-02-16 08:45:42', NULL, 1, 1, NULL);
```

Comment: What is the constraint in the table? Are there other rows in the table? The error occurs while executing which line?

Comment: i'm giving you the fuiddle link 1min